# Convert a Nuget Package to match with Xamarin C#

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, nuget-package

I recently started to develop android apps with Xamarin for Visual studio, but every time I want to install a Nuget package for C#.Net I get this error Message:

> The package "System.Reflection.Extensions 4.0.0" couldn't be installed. You try to install the package into a project, which refers to MonoAndroid,Version=v7.1", the package doesn't contain assemblyreferences or contentfiles, which are compatible with this framework. Contact the Autor of the nuget package for more information.

Is there any way to modify the nugetpackage to match my needs or do I really have to contact the author of the package?

Comment: Install version 4.3.0 instead.

Comment: That just helped a bit. After I installed it I got the same error with the initial NugetPackage. I want to install the Overwatch.Net package.

Comment: Elaborate please

Comment: edited my comment, sorry :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't install the Overwatch.Net package because it only targets .NET 4.5.2 and does not contain libraries for either PCL or Xamarin.Android.

Looking at the code for the library, there is no reason it could not be a PCL, so you have 2 options.

1. Ask the author of Overwatch.NET to make a PCL or NETStandard version of the library
2. Do the work yourself and convert it

Comment: Thx, I will try to convert it myself in next time.